# How to get timezone abbreviation from given timestamp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, datetime, jestjs

I'm running into an issue while testing two functions that convert ISO and Epoch timestamp to the client timezone. The tests are passing but I'm trying to modify them so we don't have to keep changing them based on Daylight time.

I added a bit of code to obtain the timezone abbreviation using `Date()` and `toLocaleTimeString()` and it works, except it fails in the CI/CD pipeline as the server returns UTC time. Even though, I'm adding options to specifically set the zone to America/Chicago, the server doesn't seem to recognize them.

```
describe('convertISO8601ToClientTimezone', () => {
  const timestamp = '2021-04-08T19:15:42.410506Z';
  const zoneAbbr = new Date(timestamp)
    .toLocaleTimeString('en-us', { timeZone: "America/Chicago", timeZoneName: 'short' })
    .split(' ')[2];

  it('should take ISO-8601 return date formatted string of local timezone offset accordingly', () => {
    expect(convertISO8601ToClientTimezone(timestamp)).toEqual(
      `April 8th 2021, 2:15:42 PM ${zoneAbbr}`
    );
  });
});

describe('convertEpochTimestampToClientTimezone', () => {
  const timestamp = 1617909517024179200; // epoch in nanoseconds
  const zoneAbbr = new Date(timestamp / 100000)
    .toLocaleTimeString('en-us', { timeZoneName: 'short' })
    .split(' ')[2];

  it('should take epoch timestamp and return date formatted string of local timezone offset accordingly', () => {
    expect(convertEpochTimestampToClientTimezone(timestamp)).toEqual(
      `April 8th 2021, 2:18:37 PM ${zoneAbbr}`
    );
  });
});
```

Is there a better way to get the timezone abbreviation for America/Chicago based on a given timestamp?

I'm also using the Moment library but I'm struggling to figure out how get the value needed from the mock fn. And actually, I'm not sure that would be the recommended approach here but I'm pretty new to Jest.

Comment: It would be easier (or less cumbersome) to store every timestamp as UTC. Then convert from that to whichever timezone.

Comment: @GetSet not really what I'm asking. I'm just trying to figure out a consistent way of getting the timezone abbreviation either using Moment or something else.

Comment: The timezone abbreviation when expressed as UTC is just +hours or -hours from that source. So all you would be doing is adding hours or subtracting hours. This is what makes dealing with UTC easier than say, converting between two different timezones.

Comment: @GetSet oh I see. I haven't seen examples of this yet. Do you have one I can see?

Comment: 1617909517024179200 is not a valid ECMAScript time value, it seems to be nanoseconds not milliseconds. Civil timezone names and abbreviations aren't standardised so don't use them for anything technical. *convertEpochTimestampToClientTimezone* seems to have the same code as *convertISO8601ToClientTimezone*, which only returns the abbreviation (perhaps), so will never equal `\`April 8th 2021, 2:18:37 PM ${zoneAbbr}\``. The way you're getting the timezone abbreviation is probably as good as any, but while it might work for US CDT/CST, it will not be reliable in general.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment-timezone library
https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Would I need to mock it though? Or simply import it and use the variable in my tests?

Comment: You can import it and use it